# QT SQLITE LNK1104 VISUAL STUDIO

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

[Project Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5Vzj.png)

I get this Error when I run this code. Am I forgetting to link something?

```
#include "QtGuiApplication2.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

db.setDatabaseName("./test.db");

if (!db.open())
{
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    qFatal("Failed to connect.");
}

qDebug("Connected!");
 }
```

Error:
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file '.obj'    QtGuiApplication2

Comment: Is your `QtGuiApplication2.cpp` file part of the project? It's not enough for it to be in the same directory on disk, it must be in the actual Visual Studio project as well.

Comment: Yes, The QtGuiApplication2.cpp is part of my solution. I'll add a picture of my project files